# Displaying representation symbology (lines with markers) in ArcMap legend?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, arcgis-10.5, representation

I have a polyline feature class with numerous cartographic representations of line types. Some of these representations only have a line component (see top-half image below) while other representations also have a marker component that repeats along the line (see bottom-half image below). In this case, a question mark repeats across the line type of an uncertain geologic boundary.

[image: View of different representation types in Symbology tab of Properties window.]

The representation/symbology appears correct here in the Symbology tab. But when I create a legend for this feature class, the marker part of the representation does not appear.

[image]

I thought maybe the default "patch" displayed in the legend was too short, and if a long enough patch were displayed then the marker component of the representation would be placed. But when I try to change the Default Patch Width in the Legend Properties > Layout tab, the line length in the legend remains the same and only the space between the patch and the label increases.

How do I properly display all the components of my representations in my legend (the line and the markers on the line)?